# "Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

How can I solve this error?

> Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

[image]

---

This is [my `babel.config.js` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0d3g2.png) :

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

My code:

```js
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { View, useWindowDimensions, Button } from 'react-native'
import Animated, { runOnUI } from 'react-native-reanimated';

export default function Login() {
  const { width, height } = useWindowDimensions();
  // const value = useSharedValue(0);
  function someWorklet(greeting: any) {
    'worklet';
    console.log("Hey I'm running on the UI thread");
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="click me" onPress={() => runOnUI(someWorklet)('Howdy')} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

[The package I installed](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/2.x/fundamentals/installation) is `"react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0"`.

Comment: Very similar:
[Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70516450).

Answer (score 159):

I have found this issue on this [link](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/1875).
These are the steps that I have followed for having my project up and running without any errors:

1. Run `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next react-native-gesture-handler`
2. I have added `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` to App.tsx file at the top of the file before importing any packages
3. You should update the `babel.config.js` file and add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to plugins

```json
module.exports = {
  presets: ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
};
```

4. The last thing you should do is run your project by removing the cache `yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: For my folks using expo, on the last step, step 4, use expo r -c instead

Comment: Feb 2022: cache cleaner is a killer thing that made everything works for me, thanks. Besides, everything works fine even without step 2, though it is recommended in docs during installation

Comment: Just this comment solved the issue. expo r -c

Comment: For others still having issues, don't foget about `.babelrc` I had both `babel.config` and `.babelrc` and wasn't adding it to `.babelrc`

Comment: My config was already ok. Reset cache did the job. I guess configuring it is pretty easy and straight forward following the installation guide. That's why cache was the problem for most of us.

Comment: I should mention that by running `yarn add react-native-reanimated@next` you are going to have `reanimated@3^` installed in your project

Comment: Step 4 is the key.

Comment: After doing the above mentioned change, running the command  `expo r -c` worked for me.

Comment: I only use `expo r -c` and it works.

Comment: If using NPM, this command was the one that worked for me in step 4: `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 112):

Here is what worked for me in an Expo project.

This is my *`babel.config.js`*.

> Note that `react-native-reanimated/plugin` must be at the last plugin in the plugins array of the *`babel.config.js`*.

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
        },
      ],
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ],
  };
};
```

Make sure you add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` as the last element of the `plugins`

Then stop the `expo-server` and run the following command:

```
expo r -c
```

It's all done.

Comment: I was updating my expo project......you may have just prevented me from having a stroke....

Comment: Logged in just to upvote this. Thanks!

Comment: This works in for my expo project. THANKS

Comment: This worked for me today on expo 44 version.

Comment: just excellent. thanks dear

Comment: That work, It works, the documentation makes it very easy for us to misunderstand:
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };

Comment: Nice try, but it didn't work for me. Sorry!

Comment: Saved my life man!

Answer (score 60):

Clearing the cache worked for me, run:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Comment: In my case, It also required me to install react-native-gesture-handler

Answer (score 24):

If you are using Expo try to start your app with `expo r -c` in order to clear caches associated with your project.

Answer (score 23):

Just add the below code in babel.config.js

```
 module.exports = {
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],

      // add the below line 
      plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], 
     // this should be always last line
    };
```

then if you need to clear the package manager cache and start it clean if you are using

**yarn**

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

**npx**

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

and it worked for me

Answer (score 16):

I faced the same issue. The following command solved the issue:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated@~2.2.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: i was stuck for 5 hour then i found this and solved my problem thank you

Comment: worked for me from 2.3 to 2.2

Answer (score 6):

Just adding "plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']", in my babel.config did the trick for me.

My babel.config.js file look like this now.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

then I fully cleaned my RN project by running these:

```
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf yarn.lock package-lock.json node_modules
rm -rf android/app/build
rm ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock 
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
npm install && cd ios && pod update && cd ..
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

You should run one by one or one line command.

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf yarn.lock package-lock.json node_modules && rm -rf android/app/build && rm ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock && rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData && npm install && cd ios && pod update && cd ..
```

Hope this help to someone.

Comment: Since last few days I was facing an issue and was not able to fix this. However your steps helps me and now I fixed this. You saved me. Thansk a million. Keep up th good work

Comment: From your react-native directory, you can also use `npx react-native clean` to more quickly clean your project instead of typing all those commands 

Answer (score 4):

I also came around this problem while implementing the reanimated 2 package. For me it seems a half configured installation issue. I am using React Native CLI and Windows Machine.
This is what worked for me :

1. Delete the node_modules folder and run this just to be sure.

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

2. Run

```
npm install
```

3. In babel.cofig.js add these lines. the Reanimated plugin has to be the last item in the plugins array.

```
//babel.config.js
module.exports = {
      ...
      plugins: [
          ...
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin', // << add
      ],
  };
```

4. Turn on Hermes engine by editing android/app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
  enableHermes: true  
]
```

5.Plug Reanimated in MainApplication.java. This file is present in android/app/src/main/java/com/appname folder.

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JSIModulePackage; // << add
import com.swmansion.reanimated.ReanimatedJSIModulePackage; // << add
  ...
  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
  ...

      @Override
      protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
        return "index";
      }

      **@Override //<<add this function
      protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
        return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage(); 
      }**
    };
```

This is actually availaible in there installation docs.
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

Answer (score 4):

I just add `react-native-reanimated/plugin` to `babel.config.json` in `plugins` array

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [some thing],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
  ],
};
```

and after that `expo start -c`

and error solved no need do extra steps

Answer (score 3):

In my condition i will change my babel.config.js to different this

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      [
        "module-resolver",
        {
          extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
        },
      ],
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ],
  };
};
```

Don't Forget to type this command on your project directory

```
expo r -c
```

Comment: just copy of babel.confi.js my code and paste it to yours

Comment: expo r -c is for clearing cache of your project

Comment: Can you [edit] your answer to include your comments, and then delete your comments? Comments are useful for the community to ask for clarification, but as the author of the answer, it's better to just update your answer to be fully self-contained, without relying on the comments for further clarification.

Comment: But here are i nothing comments are added

Answer (score 2):

Delete node_modules and reinstall, and make sure to delete all caches and all previous settings -- RN caches, packager caches, simulator caches and settings, etc. It might even help to go to a previous version of your app when you hadn't tried to install version 2 at all.

I am using expo and following all these steps was helpful :- https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-clear-the-expo-and-react-native-packager-caches-metro-watchman-haste/1352

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
         
      ],
    },
  },
  plugins: [ 
    [ 
      'module-resolver',
      {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json'], 
      },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ]
};
```

and then rebuild your application or run `yarn start --reset-cache`

Answer (score 2):

follow these steps

1. `expo install react-native-reanimated`
2. After the installation completed, add the Babel plugin to babel.config.js:

```
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

3. `expo start --clear`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you have done all setups but you are getting errors then just type this cmd:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

It will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**I can help you to solve this error**

Make sure Your have installed Reanimated

To install :

```
npm install react-native-reanimated
```

If you done it already that’s good

- Now add this plugins in your `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'], --> // This one
};
```

Sometimes you have done all setups properly but still getting errors then just type:

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

If still getting Errors: Close your terminal and simulator/Emulator and just type

```
\\ For Android 
 
npx react-native run-android

\\ For IOS

npx react-native run-ios
```

Hope This will Work !

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered the same issue with my newly created Expo app and attempted the solutions discussed here without success. However, I managed to solve the problem with the following steps:

Initially, my babel.config.js looked like this:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: [
      "react-native-reanimated/plugin",
    ],
  };
};
```

I modified it to:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

Subsequently, I cleared the cache and restarted the app using the following command:

```
npx expo start -c
```

A piece of advice for users of **'@react-navigation/native'**: avoid adding the **'NavigationContainer'** to your **'AppEntry'** file.

This is how I successfully resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

After you add the Babel plugin, restart your development server and clear the bundler cache: `expo start --clear`.

*Note: If you load other Babel plugins, the Reanimated plugin has to be the last item in the plugins array.*

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated@next
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Add Reanimated's babel plugin to your babel.config.js.

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset',
    '@babel/preset-typescript'
  ],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this on a freshly created expo project (tabs template). It generated the following default babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo']
  };
};
```

I added just one line, like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
  };
};
```

and cleared the rebuild cache (`yarn start -c`).

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue yesterday and when I did a Google search I landed here. After some digging here is what I understood:

1. Reanimated v2's latest version does not run in Expo when in debug mode. So I tried to open the developer options to turn off debugging by shaking the device but I was not able to.
2. Then I found that you can toggle to production mode once the Metro Bundler server connection is established. Once you toggle to production mode in Expo, the app works.
   [Enabling Production mode in Expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyrL6.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me. My babel.config was:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  env: {
    production: {
      plugins: [
        'react-native-paper/babel',
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ],      
    },
  },
};
```

I changed to this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
        'react-native-paper/babel',
        'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ]      
   
};
```

And did all the instructions at https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using expo, what worked for me is

```
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

1. install expo
   **expo install react-native-reanimated**
2. add babel.config.js
   **plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']**
3. start server
   **expo start --clear**

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade from `2.8.0` to `2.9.1` (the latest stable version). Also `3.0.0-rc` worked too.

You can see the latest versions on the `Versions` tab [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated).

Change it in your `package.json` file:

```
"react-native-reanimated": "2.9.1",
```

And run `yarn` again to download the package.

We had a `.babelrc` and `babel.config.json` and only the config had our reanimated plugin so I consolidated them but that didn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For `"react-native-reanimated": "~2.12.0"`

**Step 1:**

Add `import 'react-native-gesture-handler'` to **App.ts file at the top of the fil**e before importing any packages

**Step 2:**

Go to the `babel.config.js` and `add plugins array`:-

```
module.exports = function (api) {   

api.cache(true);  

 return {     '

        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],     
        plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"//must be in the end of plugins array],
  };

 };
```

**Step 3:**

Run `npx expo -c`

Resources:

*1.*https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator

[image: react-native-reanimated]

**2**-https://www.reanimated2.com/docs/fundamentals/installation

**3**-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130651/reanimated-2-failed-to-create-a-worklet-maybe-you-forgot-to-add-reanimateds-ba/68694681#68694681

Answer (score 0):

set you babel.config.js in the main directory like as below

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when after add **[React-Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org)** to my React-Native project.

1. Close Metro
2. `gradlew clean` //if need
3. Close emulator
4. delete app //if need
5. `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

its works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue

running `npx expo start -c` in my terminal solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

Sharing because this happened to me
My Config was

```
{
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    env: {
      production: {
        plugins: ["react-native-paper/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
      },
    },
  };
};
```

The config that worked for me (I was building for dev, but my config was set for production)

```
{
    presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    plugins: ["react-native-paper/babel", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],
 
};
```