# Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?, js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, react-native

i have a promblem with React-native-Reanimated.
I received "Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?, js engine: hermes"
But I've already followed https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation
[image]

Here is my version in reanimated:

```
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.3.0"
```

Here is my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you very much

Comment: I was having the same problem today, turns out my babel config didn't contain `plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],`, so it worked after adding it!

Comment: i've already add it, but it is run now, just... don't know what happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130651/reanimated-2-failed-to-create-a-worklet-maybe-you-forgot-to-add-reanimateds-ba)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **expo**, instead of installing using npm use:

```
expo install react-native-reanimated
```

In the babel.config.js use it like this:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```