# [ Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin? ]

Tags: android, react-native, expo, babeljs

I am using react-native expo and I got this error while android bundling.

```
Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?
```

Comment: Add `import "react-native-gesture-handler";` on your root file(App.js or index.js).

Comment: I already added `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';` to index.js

Comment: This is the version of the package on package.json `"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2"`

Comment: Can you try other solutions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130651/reanimated-2-failed-to-create-a-worklet-maybe-you-forgot-to-add-reanimateds-ba) link?

Comment: @ReactDev Did you figure it out?

Comment: It was due to expo cash problem.
I restarted expo using `expo r -c` and it works

Comment: None of the above worked.  Any other thoughts?  Running on a Mac M1