# "Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am trying to use **createDrawerNavigator** via 
`import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';` 
in [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started). 
However, I am getting the error below, which I don't know how to solve.

> Error: Requiring module
> "node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js", which threw an
> exception: Error: Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you
> forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?

In *babel.config.js*, I tried the code below, but it's not working :

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ]
  };
};
```

Here is [my component](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/drawer-based-navigation/#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation) :

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Very similar:
[Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67130651).

Comment: Here is my solution for Reanimated **3**, which is the current version:
[Answer to "Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77273990)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please complete the setup for `react-native-reanimated`.
You have to add `'react-native-reanimated/plugin',` in the babel.config.js file so the final code in babel.config.js will look like

```
module.exports = {
      ...
      plugins: [
          ...
          'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
      ],
  };
```

As state in the setup docs for `react-native-reanimated`[Here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#babel-plugin)

Also you need to complete setup for android as well (if not done yet) as stated [Here](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#android)

If you are using expo then [follow these steps](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#installation)

Finally, run **expo r -c** to clear the cache.

Comment: @lewismachilika After adding this you have to restart the packager. Run expo start again

Comment: This didn't help me, `RN - 0.68.2`, `@react-navigation/drawer@^6.4.2` `react-native-reanimated@~2.8.0`, are these version compatible each other , should I different version. Can anyone help pls

Answer (score 25):

If you are using expo. Set this in babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

Note: If you load other Babel plugins, the Reanimated plugin has to be the last item in the plugins array

After you add the Babel plugin, restart your development server and clear the bundler cache: `expo start --clear`.

Answer (score 2):

You must install according to these instructions:

[https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/][1]

Also, make no mistake Be careful where you write the following code

```
@Override
protected JSIModulePackage getJSIModulePackage() {
return new ReanimatedJSIModulePackage();  }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Solution][1]

```
  yarn add react-native-reanimated
  cd ios
  pod install
```

And Import on either Index or App .js file
`import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';`
[1]: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/1.x.x/getting_started/

Answer (score 2):

I am using react-native 0.69.3 and also had an issue with compiling reanimated@2.10. I updated to @2.11.0 and it fixed my compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure react-native-reanimated is up to date and the other packages are the same then try running `npx react-native link react-native-reanimated`.

If that didn't work you need to set up react-native-reanimated properly. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/) on how to set it up.

Comment: This is not solving the issue

Answer (score 1):

According to react navigations drawer [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation).

1. After installing all the packages
2. To finalize installation of react-native-gesture-handler, add the following at the top (make sure it's at the top and there's nothing else before it) of your entry file, such as index.js or App.js:

   `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

Now this might now work for you. To complete the installation you have to change your **babel.config.js** file add the following:

```
plugins: [...,"react-native-reanimated/plugin"]
```

**Note ... just means your other plugins if you have. Remove it if you don't have any.**

You are almost there. The final thing you have to know and do is:

> Note: If you load other Babel plugins, the Reanimated plugin has to be
> the last item in the plugins array.

> After you add the Babel plugin, restart your development server and
> clear the bundler cache: `expo start --clear`

You can reference the  [expo reanimated docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#installation) for more details

Answer (score 1):

Add this to `babel.config.js` file:

```
    module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
```

then run this to clear cache and restart development server:

```
npx expo start --clear
```

learn [more](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#installation) on expo official doc.