# "Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js?"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, babeljs, react-native-reanimated

How can I resolve the following error?

> Error: Failed to create a worklet.
> Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js?
> See installation docs at https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation#babel-plugin. <sup>1</sup>

[image: "Error: Failed to create a worklet."]

#### Background

In an [Expo app](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app), I followed [the instructions on how to install a drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation) : <sup>2</sup>

1. `npm install @react-navigation/native`
2. `npm install @react-navigation/drawer`
3. `npm install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

I then went on to try a [minimal example of drawer-based navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation). 
It's a simple application that [can be run online](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=web&dependencies=react-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fdrawer-based-navigation.js). 
The minimal example has merely one file containing React Native code, which contains a `HomeScreen` and a `NotificationsScreen`, in addition to the main `App` component.

Out of precaution, I started the project with a command that cleans the **npm** cache : <sup>3</sup>

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

I then pressed <kbd>`a`</kbd> for Android (it's <kbd>`i`</kbd> for iOS) and <kbd>`r`</kbd> to reload. 
Every time I do this, I get the error shown in the screenshot above. <sup>4</sup>

---

`babel.config.js` :

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

---

`App.js` :

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
        title="Go to notifications"
      />
    </View>
  );
}
function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} title="Go back home" />
    </View>
  );
}
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

---

`package.json` :

```json
{
  "name": "reanimated-demo",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.8",
    "expo": "~49.0.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "semver": "^7.5.4"
  }
}
```

### References

- [The documentation on how to use the `create-expo-app` package](https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app)
- [The documentation instructions on how to install a drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation)
- [Cheat sheet: npm vs yarn commands](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-npm-yarn-cheatsheet)
- [A minimal example of drawer-based navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-based-navigation/#minimal-example-of-drawer-based-navigation)
- [Link to run the minimal example online](https://snack.expo.io/?platform=web&dependencies=react-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.4.1%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.10&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Fdrawer-based-navigation.js)
- [A minimal project I use to reproduce the Reanimate error](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77273989/77273989.zip)

---

<sup>1</sup>
The link in the error message leads to a **Page Not Found** page.

<sup>2</sup>
The corresponding [Yarn](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-npm-yarn-cheatsheet) commands are :

a. `yarn add @react-navigation/native` 
b. `yarn add @react-navigation/drawer` 
c. `yarn add react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated`

<sup>3</sup>
For Yarn, the command is `yarn start --reset-cache`.

<sup>4</sup>
To reproduce: [download](https://github.com/henk9/Henke/raw/main/StackOverflow-Q77273989/77273989.zip) and unzip to some directory of your choice. 
Switch to that directory and run `npm install` and then `npm start -- --reset-cache`. 
(You'll also need an emulator or a physical device on which you run the application.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the error, there are two things you *must* do.

1. Add `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` as the *last plugin* in `babel.config.js`. 
   In your case, the updated file will be :

```js
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
  };
};
```

2. You must clear the cache when restarting the server, exactly what you already do :

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

Note that you must do *both* those steps. 
If you omit one of them, the Reanimated error will prevail. <sup>1</sup>

[image: The Reanimated error has been resolved.]

#### Why you got the error

[The instructions on how to install a drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation) are missing the two steps above that you must take to avoid the error.
The steps I refer to, are called *step 2* and *step 3* in [the documentation on how to install Reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#step-2-add-reanimateds-babel-plugin). <sup>2</sup>

### References

- [The home page of the **npm** package manager](https://www.npmjs.com/)
- [The documentation instructions on how to install a drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation)
- [Steps 2 and 3 in the documentation on how to install Reanimated](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/getting-started/#step-2-add-reanimateds-babel-plugin)
- [The home page of the `react-native-reanimated` package, v. 3.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated/v/3.3.0)

---

<sup>1</sup>
No [**npm**](https://www.npmjs.com/) package should *ever* depend on what is in the cache.
Unfortunately, the Reanimated package violates this rule.
It's not a big deal, now that you know how to work around it. 
Just add `plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],` to your `babel.config.js`, 
and then clean the cache when starting the server, `npm start -- --reset-cache`. 
If you're not happy with that, you'll need to find and fix the bug and then make a pull request.

<sup>2</sup>
Reanimated's *step 1* is to install the [`react-native-reanimated`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-reanimated/v/3.3.0) package itself. 
You already did that when following [the instructions on how to install the drawer navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#installation).