# why is this error shows even after I installed the reanimated and configured it in Babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

Uncaught Error Failed to create a worklet. Did you forget to add Reanimated Babel plugin in babel.config.js? See installation docs at https://docs swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals /installation#babel-pl

the code was right before as I tried to add drawer in my code screens it started to show this error.

I  I installed the reanimated and  aslo configured it in Babel.cofig.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reanimated 2 failed to create a worklet, maybe you forgot to add Reanimated's babel plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67130651/reanimated-2-failed-to-create-a-worklet-maybe-you-forgot-to-add-reanimateds-ba)